# UIScrollview never decelerates when pagingEnabled = YES and frame.size.width > 2000

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

The UIScrollView continues to move even after you've stopped dragging. This happens when the width of the frame is larger than 2000.

I've made a sample project demonstrating this. Has anybody else encountered this or know why this might happen?

https://bitbucket.org/tmao/buggyscrollview